# Product of two continuous functions is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y, \tilde{\tau})$ be two topological space, $f$ and $g$ be two continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ then prove that $f*g$ is continuous? Where $$ f*g(x) = f(x)*g(x) $$.

Comment: What is the definition of $f(x)*g(x)$ ? A product ? But a product makes no sense.

Answer (score 7):

I think you meant the following: Let $f:A \to B$ and $g:C\to D$ be continuous functions. The map $f \times g:A \times C \to B \times D$ given by the equation
$$ (f \times g)(a \times c)=f(a) \times g(c).$$
is continuous.

*Proof.* Let $U \times V$ be a basis element for $B \times D.$ Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$ and $g^{-1}(V)$ is open in $C.$ Moreover,
$$a \times c \in (f\times g)^{-1}(U \times V) \Leftrightarrow f(a) \times g(c) \in U \times V \Leftrightarrow a \in f^{-1}(U) \text{ and} \hspace{1mm} c \in g^{-1}(C).$$
Thus
$$ (f \times g)^{-1}(U \times V)=f^{-1}(U) \times g^{-1}(V),$$
so $(f \times g)^{-1}(U \times V)$ is open in $A \times C$(because product of open sets is open). Since preimages of basis elements  for $B \times D$ are open in $A \times C,$ then preimages of arbitrarily open subsets of $B \times D$ are open in $A \times C.$ Therefore, $f \times g$ is continuous.

In your case, let $A=C=X$ and $B=D=Y.$

Answer (score 0):

If $Y$ indeed has some continuous operation $\ast$ defined on it (like a topological (semi)group), so a continuous map $\mu: Y \times Y \to Y$ defined by $\mu(x,y) = x \ast y$ (no assumptions on it besides being continuous ) then
$f \ast g$ is indeed continuous.

To see this, first define $f \nabla g: X \to Y \times Y$ by $ (f\nabla g)(x) = (f(x), g(x))$ which is continuous whenever $f$ and $g$ are, as $\pi_1 \circ (f \nabla g) = f$ and $\pi_2 \circ (f \nabla g) = g$ are both continuous (and we have the universal mapping theorem for products). Alternatively note that $(f \nabla g)^{-1}[U \times V] = f^{-1}[U] \cap g^{-1}[V]$ for basic open sets of $Y \times Y$.

Then note that $f \ast g = \mu \circ (f \nabla g)$ is continuous as a composition of continuous maps.